# Laravel: Vue.js page not displaying in production environment

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a project in Laravel. I'm using vue.js components inside Laravel blade files. So far, I have a component called "Index.vue" which is loaded from index.blade.php. Another component called "create.vue" which is loaded from "create.blade.php". The problem is Create.vue component is not displaying when I click the button "create a new service" from index.blade.php. All the other Vue.js components works fine, but this issue is only for that particular component. I have tried to run "npm run dev" and changed webpack.mix.js file but it didn't solve my problem. I don't have any issues on my local machine, only in the production environment.

index.js

```
<x-admin-master>
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div id="app">
            <Index></Index>

            <a href="{{ route('services.create') }}" class="btn btn-info">Create a new service</a>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
</x-admin-master>
```

Webpack.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .copy(
        'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts',
        'public/webfonts'
    )
    .sourceMaps()
    .version(['public/js/app.js']);
```

Create.vue

```
<template>
<div>
      <p v-if="errors.length">
        <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
        </ul>
        </p>

    <form @submit.prevent="addService" action="/api/services" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter service name" v-model="services.name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vendor">Vendor: </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="vendor" placeholder="select vendor" v-model="services.vendor" value="Select vendor">
                    <option name="vendor" :value="service.vendor.id" v-for="service in services">{{service.vendor.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="service">Description: </label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc" rows="3" v-model="services.desc"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex flex-row hour-price" v-if="hourAndPrice">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" name="hours" class="form-control" @click="fixedPrice = false" id="hours" placeholder="Hours" v-model="services.hours">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" @click="fixedPrice = false" id="price" placeholder="Price" v-model="services.price">
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="d-flex flex-row fixed-price" v-if="fixedPrice">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number"  @click="hourAndPrice = false" name="fixed_price" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Enter fixed price" v-model="services.fixed_price">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Add Service" class="btn btn-primary"> 

        <div class="btn-toolbar d-flex justify-content-end">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Services</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
    
    data(){
        return {
            //vendors: this.vendors,
            //projects: this.projects,
            hourAndPrice: true,
            fixedPrice: true,
            services: [],
            errors: [],

            services: {
                name: null,
                vendor: null,
                desc: null,
                hours: null,
                price: null,
                fixed_price: null
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addService(){

            let ok = ''

            if(this.services.name && this.services.vendor){
                ok = true
            }

            if(!this.services.name){
                this.errors.push('Service name is required')
            }

            if(!this.services.vendor){
                this.errors.push('Vendor ID is required')
            }

            if(ok) {
                axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
                    axios.post('/api/services', {
                        name: this.services.name,
                        vendor: this.services.vendor,
                        desc: this.services.desc,
                        hours: this.services.hours,
                        price: this.services.price,
                        fixed_price: this.services.fixed_price,
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                        window.location.href = '/admin/services';
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        loadServices: function(){
            axios.get('/api/services/getservicedata')
                .then(response => {
                    this.services = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        console.log('Successfully mounted!');
        this.loadServices()
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Did you run `npm run prod` instead of dev ?

Comment: yes, I did. Same issue